# Add date to an DataArray of float (or viceversa)

Tags: python, datetime, python-xarray, timedelta

I'm kind of new in python. I have an `xarray` DataArray which contains a variable made of floats. These floats are supposed to be seconds. I would like to add these floats to a given date:

```
2021-01-01 00:00:00 + 1 =  2021-01-01 00:00:01
...
2021-01-01 00:00:00 + 120 = 2021-01-01 00:02:00
```

in order have an array of datetime I can work with (for example to extract the events between a given interval of time)

I tried to use timedelta but it does not like DataArray. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: can you share example data or at least the `print` output of your `DataArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For standard calendar operations, [xarray works best with NumPy `datetime64` and `timedelta64` types](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#time-series-data).  In your particular case, I would recommend converting your DataArray of floats to `timedelta64` (taking into account the units of seconds), and adding those values to a `datetime64` instance.  This will produce a DataArray of type `datetime64[ns]`, which you can use in other operations:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np; import xarray as xr

In [2]: data = np.arange(10.)

In [3]: da = xr.DataArray(data, dims=["x"])

In [4]: np.datetime64("2000-01-01") + da.astype("timedelta64[s]")
Out[4]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 10)>
array(['2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-01T00:00:01.000000000',
       '2000-01-01T00:00:02.000000000', '2000-01-01T00:00:03.000000000',
       '2000-01-01T00:00:04.000000000', '2000-01-01T00:00:05.000000000',
       '2000-01-01T00:00:06.000000000', '2000-01-01T00:00:07.000000000',
       '2000-01-01T00:00:08.000000000', '2000-01-01T00:00:09.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

Comment: Great, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This is for time:

`from datetime import datetime`

`now = datetime.now()`

`current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

`print(current_time)`

This is for date:

`from datetime import date`

`today = date.today()`

`print("Today's date:", today)`

Comment: how is this related to `xarray`?